# Domain Controller not working till i make a ipconfig /renew

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-server-2003, domain-controller

I have a strange problem that i can't undrestand why it is happening, the problem is my Domain Controller doesn't response and i can't access the host by local domain for example: `nagios.amd.local` till i make an `ipconfig /renew` it is happening only on my PC, the other systems are fine. The question is why this happens? and this is a problem from my pc or server?

Thanks.

The structure of network is like this: we have two DNS servers one is Primary and other is for secondary both are running on Windows Server 2003.

The Primary DNS server also contains the DHCP service to assign the IP automatically and also the name server defined for each PC and assigned by a specific IP the configuration on the client PC is set on `Automatic` option.

**DCDIAG command output:**

```
Domain Controller Diagnosis

Performing initial setup:
   Done gathering initial info.

Doing initial required tests

   Testing server: Nombre-predeterminado-primer-sitio\VM-TEMPESTA-1
      Starting test: Connectivity
         ......................... VM-TEMPESTA-1 passed test Connectivity

Doing primary tests

   Testing server: Nombre-predeterminado-primer-sitio\VM-TEMPESTA-1
      Starting test: Replications
         [Replications Check,VM-TEMPESTA-1] A recent replication attempt failed:
            From VM-TEMPESTA-2 to VM-TEMPESTA-1
            Naming Context: DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=amd,DC=local
            The replication generated an error (1256):
            The remote system is not available. For information about network troubleshooting, see Windows Help.
            The failure occurred at 2016-11-23 15:57:19.
            The last success occurred at 2016-05-18 08:52:03.
            1551 failures have occurred since the last success.
         [VM-TEMPESTA-2] DsBindWithSpnEx() failed with error -2146893022,
         The target principal name is incorrect..
         [Replications Check,VM-TEMPESTA-1] A recent replication attempt failed:
            From VM-TEMPESTA-2 to VM-TEMPESTA-1
            Naming Context: DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=amd,DC=local
            The replication generated an error (1256):
            The remote system is not available. For information about network troubleshooting, see Windows Help.
            The failure occurred at 2016-11-23 15:57:19.
            The last success occurred at 2016-05-18 08:52:03.
            1551 failures have occurred since the last success.
         [Replications Check,VM-TEMPESTA-1] A recent replication attempt failed:
            From VM-TEMPESTA-2 to VM-TEMPESTA-1
            Naming Context: CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=amd,DC=local
            The replication generated an error (-2146893022):
            The target principal name is incorrect.
            The failure occurred at 2016-11-23 15:57:19.
            The last success occurred at 2016-05-18 08:52:03.
            1550 failures have occurred since the last success.
         [Replications Check,VM-TEMPESTA-1] A recent replication attempt failed:
            From VM-TEMPESTA-2 to VM-TEMPESTA-1
            Naming Context: CN=Configuration,DC=amd,DC=local
            The replication generated an error (-2146893022):
            The target principal name is incorrect.
            The failure occurred at 2016-11-23 15:57:19.
            The last success occurred at 2016-05-18 09:28:36.
            1550 failures have occurred since the last success.
         [Replications Check,VM-TEMPESTA-1] A recent replication attempt failed:
            From VM-TEMPESTA-2 to VM-TEMPESTA-1
            Naming Context: DC=amd,DC=local
            The replication generated an error (-2146893022):
            The target principal name is incorrect.
            The failure occurred at 2016-11-23 15:57:19.
            The last success occurred at 2016-05-18 09:45:22.
            1551 failures have occurred since the last success.
         REPLICATION-RECEIVED LATENCY WARNING
         VM-TEMPESTA-1:  Current time is 2016-11-23 16:18:20.
            DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=amd,DC=local
               Last replication recieved from VM-TEMPESTA-2 at 2016-05-18 09:02:56.
               WARNING:  This latency is over the Tombstone Lifetime of 60 days!
            DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=amd,DC=local
               Last replication recieved from VM-TEMPESTA-2 at 2016-05-18 09:02:56.
               WARNING:  This latency is over the Tombstone Lifetime of 60 days!
            CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=amd,DC=local
               Last replication recieved from VM-TEMPESTA-2 at 2016-05-18 09:02:56.
               WARNING:  This latency is over the Tombstone Lifetime of 60 days!
            CN=Configuration,DC=amd,DC=local
               Last replication recieved from VM-TEMPESTA-2 at 2016-05-18 09:39:31.
               WARNING:  This latency is over the Tombstone Lifetime of 60 days!
            DC=amd,DC=local
               Last replication recieved from VM-TEMPESTA-2 at 2016-05-18 09:56:16.
               WARNING:  This latency is over the Tombstone Lifetime of 60 days!
         ......................... VM-TEMPESTA-1 passed test Replications
      Starting test: NCSecDesc
         ......................... VM-TEMPESTA-1 passed test NCSecDesc
      Starting test: NetLogons
         ......................... VM-TEMPESTA-1 passed test NetLogons
      Starting test: Advertising
         ......................... VM-TEMPESTA-1 passed test Advertising
      Starting test: KnowsOfRoleHolders
         ......................... VM-TEMPESTA-1 passed test KnowsOfRoleHolders
      Starting test: RidManager
         ......................... VM-TEMPESTA-1 passed test RidManager
      Starting test: MachineAccount
         ......................... VM-TEMPESTA-1 passed test MachineAccount
      Starting test: Services
         ......................... VM-TEMPESTA-1 passed test Services
      Starting test: ObjectsReplicated
         ......................... VM-TEMPESTA-1 passed test ObjectsReplicated
      Starting test: frssysvol
         ......................... VM-TEMPESTA-1 passed test frssysvol
      Starting test: frsevent
         There are warning or error events within the last 24 hours after the
         SYSVOL has been shared.  Failing SYSVOL replication problems may cause
         Group Policy problems. 
         ......................... VM-TEMPESTA-1 failed test frsevent
      Starting test: kccevent
         ......................... VM-TEMPESTA-1 passed test kccevent
      Starting test: systemlog
         An Error Event occured.  EventID: 0x40000004
            Time Generated: 11/23/2016   15:34:30
            Event String: The kerberos client received a
         An Error Event occured.  EventID: 0x40000004
            Time Generated: 11/23/2016   15:38:37
            Event String: The kerberos client received a
         An Error Event occured.  EventID: 0x40000004
            Time Generated: 11/23/2016   15:45:55
            Event String: The kerberos client received a
         An Error Event occured.  EventID: 0x40000004
            Time Generated: 11/23/2016   15:57:19
            Event String: The kerberos client received a
         An Error Event occured.  EventID: 0x40000004
            Time Generated: 11/23/2016   16:09:56
            Event String: The kerberos client received a
         ......................... VM-TEMPESTA-1 failed test systemlog
      Starting test: VerifyReferences
         ......................... VM-TEMPESTA-1 passed test VerifyReferences

   Running partition tests on : ForestDnsZones
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... ForestDnsZones passed test CrossRefValidation
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... ForestDnsZones passed test CheckSDRefDom

   Running partition tests on : DomainDnsZones
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... DomainDnsZones passed test CrossRefValidation
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... DomainDnsZones passed test CheckSDRefDom

   Running partition tests on : Schema
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... Schema passed test CrossRefValidation
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... Schema passed test CheckSDRefDom

   Running partition tests on : Configuration
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... Configuration passed test CrossRefValidation
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... Configuration passed test CheckSDRefDom

   Running partition tests on : amd
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... amd passed test CrossRefValidation
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... amd passed test CheckSDRefDom

   Running enterprise tests on : amd.local
      Starting test: Intersite
         ......................... amd.local passed test Intersite
      Starting test: FsmoCheck
         ......................... amd.local passed test FsmoCheck
```

IPCONFIG output of SERVER:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\administrador>ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 172.27.2.90
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.224.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 172.27.31.254
```

**IPCONFIG /ALL my PC:**

```
    C:\Windows\system32>ipconfig /all

Configuración IP de Windows

   Nombre de host. . . . . . . . . : COMMERCIAL
   Sufijo DNS principal  . . . . . :
   Tipo de nodo. . . . . . . . . . : híbrido
   Enrutamiento IP habilitado. . . : no
   Proxy WINS habilitado . . . . . : no
   Lista de búsqueda de sufijos DNS: amd.local

Adaptador de Ethernet local connection:

   Sufijo DNS específico para la conexión. . : amd.local
   Descripción . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controlle
r
   Dirección física. . . . . . . . . . . . . : D4-3D-7E-A9-57-E8
   DHCP habilitado . . . . . . . . . . . . . : sí
   Configuración automática habilitada . . . : sí
   Vínculo: dirección IPv6 local. . . : fe80::f068:1507:a78b:bb55%11(Preferido)

   Dirección IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 172.27.17.7(Preferido)
   Máscara de subred . . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.224.0
   Concesión obtenida. . . . . . . . . . . . : Wednesday, November 23, 2016 1:08
:10 PM
   La concesión expira . . . . . . . . . . . : Thursday, December 01, 2016 3:58:
56 PM
   Puerta de enlace predeterminada . . . . . : 172.27.31.254
   Servidor DHCP . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 172.27.2.90
   IAID DHCPv6 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 248790398
   DUID de cliente DHCPv6. . . . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-19-2F-AD-5D-D4-3D-7E-
A9-57-E8
   Servidores DNS. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 172.27.2.90
                                       172.27.2.91
                                       8.8.8.8
   NetBIOS sobre TCP/IP. . . . . . . . . . . : habilitado

Adaptador de Ethernet VMware Network Adapter VMnet8:

   Sufijo DNS específico para la conexión. . : localdomain
   Descripción . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter f
or VMnet8
   Dirección física. . . . . . . . . . . . . : 00-50-56-C0-00-08
   DHCP habilitado . . . . . . . . . . . . . : sí
   Configuración automática habilitada . . . : sí
   Vínculo: dirección IPv6 local. . . : fe80::a966:970d:4f63:54f1%19(Preferido)

   Dirección IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.86.1(Preferido)
   Máscara de subred . . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Concesión obtenida. . . . . . . . . . . . : Tuesday, November 22, 2016 11:41:
00 AM
   La concesión expira . . . . . . . . . . . : Thursday, November 24, 2016 8:28:
56 AM
   Puerta de enlace predeterminada . . . . . :
   Servidor DHCP . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.86.254
   IAID DHCPv6 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 637554774
   DUID de cliente DHCPv6. . . . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-19-2F-AD-5D-D4-3D-7E-
A9-57-E8
   Servidores DNS. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.86.2
   Servidor WINS principal . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.86.2
   NetBIOS sobre TCP/IP. . . . . . . . . . . : habilitado

Adaptador de túnel isatap.amd.local:

   Estado de los medios. . . . . . . . . . . : medios desconectados
   Sufijo DNS específico para la conexión. . : amd.local
   Descripción . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Adaptador ISATAP de Microsoft
   Dirección física. . . . . . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP habilitado . . . . . . . . . . . . . : no
   Configuración automática habilitada . . . : sí

Adaptador de túnel Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Estado de los medios. . . . . . . . . . . : medios desconectados
   Sufijo DNS específico para la conexión. . :
   Descripción . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface

   Dirección física. . . . . . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP habilitado . . . . . . . . . . . . . : no
   Configuración automática habilitada . . . : sí

Adaptador de túnel isatap.localdomain:

   Estado de los medios. . . . . . . . . . . : medios desconectados
   Sufijo DNS específico para la conexión. . : localdomain
   Descripción . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Adaptador ISATAP de Microsoft #3
   Dirección física. . . . . . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP habilitado . . . . . . . . . . . . . : no
   Configuración automática habilitada . . . : sí
```

**OUTPUT OF nltest /dsgetdc:amd.local**

```
    DC: \\VM-Tempesta-1.amd.local
      Dirección: \\172.27.2.90
     GUID del DOM: 28e39dee-e275-4ee9-9fc7-3ca5be07e137
     Nombre del DOM: amd.local
  Nombre del bosque: amd.local
 Nombre de sitio DC: Nombre-predeterminado-primer-sitio
Nuestro nombre de sitio: Nombre-predeterminado-primer-sitio
        Marcas: PDC GC DS LDAP KDC TIMESERV WRITABLE DNS_DC DNS_DOMAIN DNS_FORES
T CLOSE_SITE
El comando se completó correctamente
```

**OUTPUT of repadmin /showreps**

```
Nombre-predeterminado-primer-sitio\VM-TEMPESTA-2
DC Options: IS_GC
Site Options: (none)
DC object GUID: cd5f88f0-2910-4615-826b-bca3603afc3b
DC invocationID: 1057fb04-ab63-4874-a412-ff4fbb594eb7

==== INBOUND NEIGHBORS ======================================

DC=amd,DC=local
    Nombre-predeterminado-primer-sitio\VM-TEMPESTA-1 via RPC
        DC object GUID: 1a6efb04-16d2-44ac-bd6b-ebefe6046bf2
        Last attempt @ 2016-11-24 10:18:06 failed, result 1908 (0x774):
            Could not find the domain controller for this domain.
        1765 consecutive failure(s).
        Last success @ 2016-09-13 11:20:47.

CN=Configuration,DC=amd,DC=local
    Nombre-predeterminado-primer-sitio\VM-TEMPESTA-1 via RPC
        DC object GUID: 1a6efb04-16d2-44ac-bd6b-ebefe6046bf2
        Last attempt @ 2016-11-24 10:18:06 failed, result 1908 (0x774):
            Could not find the domain controller for this domain.
        1766 consecutive failure(s).
        Last success @ 2016-09-13 11:07:14.

CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=amd,DC=local
    Nombre-predeterminado-primer-sitio\VM-TEMPESTA-1 via RPC
        DC object GUID: 1a6efb04-16d2-44ac-bd6b-ebefe6046bf2
        Last attempt @ 2016-11-24 10:18:06 failed, result 1908 (0x774):
            Could not find the domain controller for this domain.
        1765 consecutive failure(s).
        Last success @ 2016-09-13 11:04:20.

DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=amd,DC=local
    Nombre-predeterminado-primer-sitio\VM-TEMPESTA-1 via RPC
        DC object GUID: 1a6efb04-16d2-44ac-bd6b-ebefe6046bf2
        Last attempt @ 2016-11-24 10:18:06 failed, result 1908 (0x774):
            Could not find the domain controller for this domain.
        1765 consecutive failure(s).
        Last success @ 2016-09-13 11:04:20.

DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=amd,DC=local
    Nombre-predeterminado-primer-sitio\VM-TEMPESTA-1 via RPC
        DC object GUID: 1a6efb04-16d2-44ac-bd6b-ebefe6046bf2
        Last attempt @ 2016-11-24 10:18:06 failed, result 1908 (0x774):
            Could not find the domain controller for this domain.
        1765 consecutive failure(s).
        Last success @ 2016-09-13 11:04:20.

Source: Nombre-predeterminado-primer-sitio\VM-TEMPESTA-1
******* 1766 CONSECUTIVE FAILURES since 2016-09-13 11:20:47
Last error: 1908 (0x774):
            Could not find the domain controller for this domain.
```

Comment: There aren't any details in your question about your configuration from which we could possibly hope to provide answers.

Comment: @joeqwerty what info is required about the configuration?

Comment: DNS configuration info for the clients and the servers, ip addressing information, like are the clients assigned an ip address from DHCP, do the servers have static ip addresses, what DNS servers do the cleints and the servers use?

Comment: @joeqwerty i updated my post i hope this will be enough

Comment: Specifically; what do the Domain Controllers and the clients use for DNS?

Comment: @joeqwerty the windows server services

Comment: I don't see any primary/secondary DNS servers defined on your PC `ipconfig /all` output. That would make it difficult to connect to your domain. When you run `ipconfig /renew`, what DNS servers are defined on the PC? You may also want to include the output of `nltest /dsgetdc:amd.local`. Also VM-TEMPESTA-2 is no longer any good because it hasn't replicated in over Tombstone Lifetime (TSL).

Comment: @GregAskew thanks for answer i updated my post, can you explain more about why the VM-TEMPESTA-2 is no longer good? and refer me to a documentation about it?

Comment: If a domain controller has not replicated within the Tombstone Lifetime period (60 days on your domain controllers), it will not be allowed to replicate again. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2020053

Answer (score 0):

DNS is the culprit a lot.  If you have working clients perfectly fine, yeah, something is up with your PC.

- Try re-joining.
- Are you sure the DNS IP you get from DHCP is the DC's IP and you aren't including a PUBLIC IP as secondary?
- IPv6 sometimes can be an issue.  Not saying to disable it, I would not.  But check your IPv6 configuration.  On the DC, right click on server and check out config.  I have been hired to fix setups where someone set the DNS server to listen to IPv6 and disabled IPv6 on all clients.  Funny stuff.

All fixable.  Please provide some details, but I have a gut feeling you fix it by now! So high five!

- DCDIAG
- IPCONFIG Server and your workstation

Cheers,
Rob

Comment: thank you i updated my post by output of commands you asked, I checked and IPv6 stack is not installed on my windows server 2003 so i think that part can not be the issue