# There is no Domain Controller in Add/Remove role

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2003, domain-controller

Recently i faced a very strange problem with my Active directory (Windows server 2003) and i asked a question here but nobody could help:

[Domain Controller not working till i make a ipconfig /renew](https://serverfault.com/questions/816589/domain-controller-not-working-till-i-make-a-ipconfig-renew?noredirect=1#comment1039257_816589)

now i found out that when i open my Add/Remove role in Manage server consol there is no DC in the list!

[The Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCpZK.jpg)

have anybody faced this kind of problem?

Comment: Did you go into the add/remove programs as the screenshot suggested if your role wasn't shown?
If not there, can you do a screenshot of that?

Comment: if you mean Add/Remove windows component no it is not there also

Answer (score 5):

Do not use Add/Remove Wizard to remove Active Directory/Domain Controller services.

Use **dcpromo** command instead.

Comment: yea but why it shouldn't be there?